# Finding the minimum value to satisfy a modulus

Tags: c, math, optimization, hash, modulus

The problem I have is x = (16807 x k) % 65536

ie 16807k ≡ x (mod 65536)

I need to calculate k knowing x.
My best effort so far is something of a brute force. Is there a mathematical way to calculate k?
If not any optimisations on my current code would be appreciated.

```
t = x;
while ( t += 15115 ) // 16807k = 65536n + x - this is the n
{
    if (t%16807 == 0)
    return t/16807;
}
return x;
```

EDIT: Changed += to 15115

Comment: x = (16807 x k) % 65536 and 16807k = x mod 65536 aren't equivalent.

Comment: Addition to @Roecrew comment: first equation has multiple `k` as an answer, second has a single `k`.

Do you need to find all `k`'s?

Comment: Dude I'm sorry but your not making any sense. Can you tell us at least what this code's application is?

Comment: Sorry, ignore the second equation - its supposed to be 16807k ≡ x (mod 65536).
Its from an encryption function. The function applied ((16807 x k) % 65536) ^ plaintext for 16bit k and plaintext was two chars.
I have the first few bytes of plaintext and am trying to decrypt it as efficiently as possible. plaintext ^ ciphertext gives me what i called x above

Comment: * Its for a university assignment. They were expecting us to brute force it. Hence i need to provide the original key as well as the plaintext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An odd numbers has a multiplicative inverse modulo a power of two.

The inverse of 16807 mod 2<sup>16</sup> is 22039.

That means that `(16807 * 22039) % 65536 == 1`, and consequently, that

```
(16807 * 22039 * x) % 65536 == x
```

And

```
k = (22039 * x) % 65536
```

So you don't have to try anything, you can simply calculate `k` directly.

Comment: This answer would be better if it properly cited the source (Warren, Henry S., Jr.. *Hacker’s Delight*. Boston: Addison-Wesley, 2003. “mulinv”, pp. 195-197.), stated that the code had been modified for a specific situation, stated the limitations on the modified code, and explained why the code works. It is a bane of software development that cryptic bits of code like this get passed around and inserted into programs, leading to unmaintainable code. This code is limited to small powers of two. A loop extends it to other powers of two, and the extended Euclidean algorithm supports any numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You solve this kind of problems using the extended euclidean algorithm for the GCD of 16807 and 65536

The remainder sequence is initiated with

```
R0=65536
R1=16807
```

and the computation of the inverse with

```
V0=0  (V0*16807 == R0 mod 65536)
V1=1  (V1*16807 == R1 mod 65536)
```

Then using integer long division,

```
Q1=R0/R1=3,
R2=R0-Q1*R1=15115
V2=V0-Q*V1=-3 (V2*16807 == R2 mod 65536)

Q2=R1/R2=1,  
R3=R1-Q2*R2=1692
V3=V1-Q2*V2=4

Q3=8,  R4=1579,  V4=-35
Q4=1,  R5=113,   V5=39
Q5=13, R6=110,   V6=-542
Q6=1,  R7=3,     V7=581
Q7=36, R8=2,     V8=-21458
Q8=1,  R9=1,     V9=22039
```

so that 22039 is found as the modular inverse of 15115 modulo 65536.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to look up `k` repeatedly for different `x`, you can build a table of solutions before you start decoding:

```
uint16_t g = 16807u;
uint16_t *mods = malloc(0x10000 * sizeof(*mods));
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++) {
    uint16_t x = g * i;    // x is effectively x mod 2**16

    mods[x] = i;
};
```

The solution to yor equation in the 16-bit-range is then:

```
uint16_t k = mods[x];
```

It is assumed that `x` is a 16-bit unsigned integer. Don't forget to `free(mods)` after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If `k` is a solution, then `k+65536` is also a solution.

The straightforward brute-force method to find the first k (k>= 0) would be:

```
for (k=0; k < 65536; k++) {
    if ( (k*16807) % 65536 == x ) {
        // Found it!
        break;
    }
}
if (k=65536) {
    // No solution found
}
return k;
```